# selecting region names based on country and region codes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a  table called `profile` which has a column `region_code` and `country_code` and another table called `regions` which has columns `country_code`, `region_name` and `region_code`. I want to select the `region_name` from table `regions` based on the `region_code` and `country_code` from table `profiles`. I thought the code below wouldwork but it always returns an empty set and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help much appreciated.Thanks.

```
SELECT region_name 
FROM regions 
WHERE country_code IN(
                       SELECT country_code 
                       FROM profiles 
                       WHERE account_name = 'me'
                      )
AND region_code IN(
                       SELECT region_code
                       FROM profiles 
                       WHERE account_name = 'me'
                      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify your query, and use something like this one:

```
SELECT region_name
FROM
  regions
WHERE
  (country_code, region_code) IN (SELECT country_code, region_code
                                  FROM   profiles
                                  WHERE  account_name = 'me')
```

but if you still get empty result, I would execute just the subquery and see what rows it returns:

```
SELECT country_code, region_code
FROM   profiles
WHERE  account_name = 'me'
```

i suspect that it doesn't return any value, or that the values returned are not present in the regions table.

Comment: I've never seen the multi-column IN clause before, is this a MySQL specific thing? I browsed the manual but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: thanks, this is better but still getting empty setit must besomething to do with the configuration of the tables themselves

Comment: @jpw it's not just for the IN clause, you could use it in your query on the join clause: ON (r.c_code, r.r_code) = (p.c_code, p.r_code) and it's not mysql specific, I think it will work in postgresql but not in Oracle or mssql as far as I know...

Comment: @fthiella Thanks, good to know. With every feature I learn about MySQL it just seems even more odd ;)

Comment: @user2014429 both queries return empty results? That means that you don't have a "me" account name

Comment: @jpw yes mysql is quite odd sometimes ;)

Comment: @fthiella there is a 'me'(realname: member1). althogh you may be on to somthing because when I take away the account_name clause I get a result. I will dig further. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2014429 then maybe the account name is not in account_name column (mmm...it would be quite strange but who knows...) or maybe it's an Id and not a string...

Comment: I changed the regions of 'member1' and now some combinations of country and region codes work, so it's not a technical error its human error in my system of linking the codes. Thanks for all the help I should be able to figure it out now I reckon.:)

Comment: correction: the issue is with regions with a ' in them. these columns do not show up

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a join?

```
SELECT r.region_name 
FROM regions r
JOIN profiles p ON r.country_code = p.country_code 
               AND r.region_code  = p.region_code
WHERE p.account_name = 'me'
```

This would list the region name for the region that maps to the specific users region code and country code.

Comment: thanks for the code, still not working though. must be another issue

Comment: You could check that the data types are the same between the tables so you don't compare a value with trailing blanks for instance, or maybe it's case sensitive.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. though all codes are INT(3) and I get no msql warnings(which come up in such a case)

Comment: @user2014429 Then I guess that you either are missing the account_name `me` or that if it exists it lacks either one or both of the two codes. Or maybe there could be a corrupted index.

Comment: I changed the regions of 'member1' and now some combinations of country and region codes work, so it's not a technical error its human error in my system of linking the codes. Thanks for all the help I should be able to figure it out now I reckon.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN queries. Makes your query sweet and simple.

```
SELECT p.region_name
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN profile p
ON r.region_code = p.region_code
AND r.country_code = p.country_code
WHERE p.account_name = "me"
```

The query you posted is alright. The reason you're not getting any data is maybe because you don't actually have any data for `account_name = "me"` in `profile` table. Or maybe your database name has changed. Whatever, your query's ok, but JOIN is simpler.